# .Net Regex to match exactly one word

Tags: .net, regex

I was wondering if this is even possible but I have:

```
Input:
ABC Construction

Database to Match:
ABC
ABC Linen
ABC Noodle
ABC Telecom
ABC Sports
```

Is there a way to write a regex to match ABC Construction to ABC ONLY, and none of the other choices?

I've tried

> ^([\w+?]\b){1}

and it's returning all 5 matches

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `if not code: print("Where's your code?")`

Comment: Forget regex, what does your question even mean? What do you mean by "match ABC Construction to ABC ONLY"? Please explain!

Comment: sorry guys, new to this, what i meant is there I am using a database matching tool that works off of .net's regex engine. It allows like sophisticated look up by various matching conditions/filters. so basically, i need to find the right account name from the input i was given. in this case there is an input "ABC Construction", and in the database I am looking up, it has the 5 options. with the .net ^([\w+?]\b){1} the tool is returning 5 matches which basically is a "first word" match. is there way to write it so that it's only returning "ABC" as the match and not the other 4?

Comment: Basically, this tool my company is like a vlookup tool. so to match ABC Construction to ABC only in Excel i'd only do VLOOKUP(LEFT("ABC Construction",3),DATABASECOLUMN,1,FALSE), and it'll only return a positive on "ABC" and none of the "ABC xxx"